# How to deploy Vue CLI App on local server?

Tags: vue.js

I have build Vue Cli App and I want to access it on another pc on the same network, how I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your app and then go to the dist directory within your terminal

Then you can install `http-server`via npm `npm install -g http-server` and go to your directory containing the app (dist folder) and just type in your terminal `http-server`